# urllib2.Request Keeps Downloading Cached File From Proxy

Tags: python, proxy, ftp

I've got a Python 2.7 script that downloads a ZIP file from a public FTP site through our corporate proxy. The proxy is set in my Windows server's system variables.

Downloading the file works, except that I discovered it's continually downloading the same version of the file even though the file is begin updated on the FTP site. It appears to be grabbing the cached version from the proxy, not the current version on the web.

Here's the code to get the file:

```
    request = urllib2.Request(download_url)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
```

How can I force the script to get the current file through the proxy, instead of the cached one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add a Cache-Control header:

```
    request = urllib2.Request(download_url)
    request.add_header('Cache-Control', 'max-age=0')
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
```

The assumption is that the proxy server is honouring the header, even though FTP requests don't support headers.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the url with ?foo=bar appended.

Comment: Alas, no query strings allowed in FTP